# GWT dealing with request error

Tags: servlets, gwt, httprequest

I have a GWT module and in it I navigate to a different URL via:

```
 Window.Location.assign(url);
```

The navigated url is then handled by a servlet, up until this point if there was an error it was handle by the resp.sendError methode

```
 resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed.");
```

Which would then navigate to the browsers error page. However I wanted to know is there away I can not navigate to an error page? i.e. I would be able to check in my GWT code if there was an error and then do something? Like resend the request ect.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Is the scenario not clear or what I am doing not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate away from your webapplication that's that. Instead of using `Window.Location.assign` you should make an [HTTP request still from your webapplication](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests), for example using [`RequestBuilder`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).
Example from the docs mentioned earlier:

```java
import com.google.gwt.http.client.*;
...

String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

try {
  Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
       // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
      if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
          // Process the response in response.getText()
      } else {
        // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
      }
    }
  });
} catch (RequestException e) {
  // Couldn't connect to server
}
```

Note that this will work only if your servlet and webapplication are on the same address (domain, port, protocol), because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?). If that's not the case, there are still [some options](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html), like JSON with padding (which GWT supports via `JsonpRequestBuilder`).

Comment: Thanks Igor I will test it and let you know